# Go mgo.v2 package error: no reachable servers

Tags: mongodb, docker, go, docker-compose, mgo

Trying to use the mgo.v2 package to connect to the mongodb server. I have started the server using:

`mongod --auth`

I am able to connect to the server using the terminal using:

`$ mongo -u "username" -p "password" --authenticationDatabase "db"`

But when I use:

`mgo.Dial("mongodb://usernamer:password@127.0.0.1:27017/dbname")`

It gives me an error saying {"error":"no reachable servers"}.

My docker-compose.yml file is as below

```
version: "2"
services:
  todo:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: todo/Dockerfile
    restart: always
    volumes:
    - .:/go/src/prac
    container_name: todo
    ports:
    - 8800:8081
  mongodb:
    command: mongod --auth
    container_name: mongodb
    image: mongo:latest
    ports:
    - 27017:27017
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem appears to be that you are trying to connect to 127.0.0.1. MongoDB is not in the same container, so this won't work.

```
mgo.Dial("mongodb://usernamer:password@127.0.0.1:27017/dbname")
```

You should instead be connecting to the MongoDB container you defined by using the name you chose.

```
mgo.Dial("mongodb://usernamer:password@mongodb:27017/dbname")
```

Docker Compose creates a [network](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/) for your containers in which they can access each other using the names you have defined as hostnames. Note that you don't need to define `ports` for containers to reach each other; these are only needed to reach containers from outside Docker.

Comment: Hi Michael. Thanks a ton. Just a follow up. How do i create users for the MongoDB container. It gives me an SASL Authentication error when i try to connect. I mean the db, collection, user and pass that i created were though the mongo shell.

Comment: That seems like a different question.